# Why can't get records by other column except id on show action with laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Laravel version: 5.4

Categories table:

```
| id | blog_id |
| -- | -- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
```

Here is the route:

```
Route::get('categories/{blog_id}', 'CategoryController@show');
```

In `CategoryController`:

```
public function show(Category $blog_id)
{
    return DB::table('categories')->where('blog_id', $blog_id)->get();
}
```

When check from url:

```
/categories/1
```

The sql is:

```
select * from `categories` where `id` = '1' limit 1
```

But not:

```
select * from `categories` where `blog_id` = '1' limit 1
```

Why?

Comment: try removing this Category from parameters you passed in function

Comment: In: public function show(Category $blog_id) $blog_id is int type not Category, try to remove or change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using route model binding here:

```
public function show(Category $blog_id)
```

What this does is it takes the `$blog_id`, and then it looks for a `Category` with an `id` of `$blog_id`.

If you want to get all categories using the `$blog_id`, simple remove the model from the method declaration:

```
public function show($blog_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Route Model Binding` takes `id` as the `parameter`. If you want to use other column instead of using `id` then just `override` the `getRouteKeyName` method on your `Eloquent` model.

```
class Category extends Model {
    public function getRouteKeyName() {
        return 'blog_id';
    }
}
```

For more details, you can see [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/cleaner-laravel-controllers-with-route-model-binding) link.

Comment: You're obviously right but I don't think it's a good solution here, since the blog_id isn't unique in OP's table and the query they want seems to be get() rather than first().

Comment: @JoelHinz thanks for noticing, i just forgot to mention uniqueness